# Centering an <a> on a newline within a <span> when the former text is aligned-left.

Tags: html, css

I have an `<a>` element nested within a `<span>` element. The `<a>` element occurs after some lines of text followed by two line breaks (`<br>`). So while the initial text within this `<span>` element needs to be `text-align: left`, I'd like to know if there is a way to change the formatting for the subsequent `<a>` element to be `text-align: center`.

I am using CSS to modify the formats and have succeeded in changing the color and text-decoration of the `<a>` element (independent of the former text), so I know that my code is pointing to the correct element, but when I try to alter the alignment it will not work for me...

Please hit me with potential solutions.... Thank you.

Comment: Why not fiddle it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: block;` it will allow the `a` element to `text-align`

```
a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/suLaagcw/2/)

Comment: Changing an inline element to block level to apply specific styles is very common :)